# VB.NET My database connection is always hacked

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, connection

I am using VB.NET 2015 with SQL Server connection for my application with a login system, I protect my assembly with .NET Reactor and everytime I publish my project protected I find that my connection string is published, I tried to encrypt my connection string inside the code and didn't work although I tried too different protections and results were the same, Everytime my connection string gets published and all tables gets dropped, I am tired of that, Is there another way of how can I protect my database connection? And what's the wrong in my database connection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us exactly what you tried.

Comment: What type of application? Where is the database located? HOW did you try to encrypt your connection string? Saying "didn't work" is useless without an explanation of expectation, method and result.

Comment: Thanks for your time, My database is SQL Server located on an online MSSQL hosting server and about the connection string encryption is too simple, I am not experienced with encryption much. I used to store the encryption keys inside the code itself, But I think they can't access the source itself because my protection is too good but I think they use a trick to get the connection string.